# Why is my image not covering my entire modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I'm using a modal as an image viewer from materialize CSS http://materializecss.com/. When a user clicks a button, the modal opens. The modal has an image element within it. I've set both the height and the width to 100% but I cannot figure out why there is still a line at the bottom that my image is not covering.[image]

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <a id="closeIcon"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
    <img class="responsive-img" id="roomImage" src="">
</div>

#roomImage{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a working fiddle?

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason you are using the modal component versus their [MaterialBox](http://materializecss.com/media.html) component to view images?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css inside your custom sytlesheet. This should work as expected.

CSS

```
.modal {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 55%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.z-depth-4, .modal {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: It is weird that this didn't fix it for me. I forgot to mention that I am using materialize css

Comment: @unconditionalcoder Check my answer above, do you think that `margin: 0;` would be of any help?

Comment: @unconditionalcoder Oh, sorry about that.  I can't think of anything else that would be causing this other than a problem with materialize css.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I like to always use to start a website.  It's a simple CSS snipet, but it works wonders.

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, hr, dl, dd, ol, ul, figure {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I first saw this in Jekyll.  Although it seems simple (and it is) it'll reset all your basic elements so that `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` will actually do what they're supposed to do.